# Mock vuex with Jest, uknown getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm quite stuck on how I test components that use vuex.

The test i'm trying to run simply tests that when run to set edit to true. The method is as follows:

```
  editMovie: function(movie){
      console.log(movie)
       this._originalMovie = Object.assign({}, movie);
       movie.edit = true;
  },
```

Some methods and on mount dispatches to the store.

I was getting errors about it can't find dispatch so followed https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html and added in the Mock store (I think...), with this:

Error:

> console.error node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:899 [vuex] unknown
>   getter: movies
>
> console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621 [Vue
>   warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of
>   undefined"

Code:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
//import Actions from '../../src/store/Actions'
import MoviesList from '@/components/MoviesList.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('MoviesList.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      getMovies: jest.fn(),
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions
    })
  })

  it('Edit should be true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MoviesList, { store, localVue })
    wrapper.setData({ 
      movies: { 0: {
          deleted:false,
          edit:false,
          name:"Full Metal Jacket",
          released_on:"1987",
      }}
    })
    console.log(wrapper.vm.movies[0])
    wrapper.vm.editMovie(wrapper.vm.movies[0])
    expect(wrapper.vm.movies[0].edit).toBe(true)
  })
})
```